# Procedural texture disappears in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders, procedural

i'm a Blender newbie trying to make my first scene without a step-by-step tutorial, and i've found a problem. I'm trying to use texture paint in a scene but it seems that using texture painting with a procedural texture at the same time is too much for my PC since the viewport got too laggy, so i switched the render mode to Cycles to bake the procedural texture's colors into an image, but on the render preview they simply disappeared and i have no idea why. At first i tought it was just a viewport glitch and tried to bake anyway but the image i baked it into turned out the same as before baking. I don't know if both glitches (the weird shading preview and the inability to bake) are related to the same issue or if they're both separate things that i did wrong...

This is how it looks in the viewport with Eevee:

[image: viewport in Eevee]

And this is what it looks when i switch to Cycles:

[image: viewport with Cycles]

This is what the node tree for the material looks like at the moment:

[image: node tree]

and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n8Aupa3-lN4LAlXH728CwDCIPgt6fXQf/view?usp=sharing) is the .blend file link.

As shown in the images, only the concrete material has this problem, the more simple ones are displayed correctly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The *Shader to RGB* node doesn't work for Cycles

Comment: I'm trying to imagine moonboots being flagged for a low quality answer.  I guess there's a first for everything!!!

Comment: at first my answer was low quality so I had to edit it  ^^

Comment: Thank you! I would never have imagined. I guess i should read the documentation before going crazy with nodes.